# stop ajax from running n number of times

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I don't know what happens there. [
Here you see the Edit buttonedit(pencil) in actions when i uopdate the record modal will open.[image]

When you click on edit(pencil) button modal will be open.
[image]

When i update the record first time its working fine and ajax runs one time. when i again update the record ajax runs twice and again update the record ajax run thrice. every time when i update the record the ajax run incremented 
Here is my code:-
Html code of Button

```
enter code here
<button  type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-edit editService"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>// this button in foreach loop
```

My Modal:-

```
enter code here
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal-edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <form id="subservicedata" role="form" method="POST" action="Javascript:;">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="add-cat">Edit Service</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <span class="col-xs-3 add-cate-model">Service</span>
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <input name="name"  id="sname" class="form-control txtfield m-tb-10" type="text" placeholder="Service" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="serviceid" id="service_id" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="listid" id="list_id" value="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary editSubService">Submit</button>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Jquery Code:-

```
enter code here
$(document).on ('click','.editService',function(){
    var tdid = $(this).parents().parents().attr('id');
    var service = tdid.split('-');
    var subserviceid = service[1];
    alert(subserviceid);
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url  : "get-service",
        data : { id: subserviceid },
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(resp){
            if($.trim(resp)){
                $('#myModal-edit').modal('show');
                $('#sname').val(resp.name);
                $('#id').val(resp.id);
                $('#service_id').val(resp.service_id);
                $('#list_id').val(resp.list_id);
                $(document).on('click','.editSubService',function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        type : "post",
                        url  : "edit-sub-service",
                        data : $("#subservicedata").serialize(),
                        success:function(resp){
                            if($.trim(resp)){
                                alert(resp); 
                                alert(subserviceid);
                                $('#tr-'+subserviceid+' #tdid-'+subserviceid).html(resp);
                                $('#myModal-edit').modal('hide');
                            }else{
                                alert("Error"); return false;
                            }
                        },
                        error:function(){
                            alert("Something Went Wrong!");
                        }
                    });
                });
            } else{
                alert("Failed"); return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And My laravel 5.2 function

```
enter code here
public function getCategoryService(Request $request){
    if($request->ajax()){
        $data = $request->all();
        $servicedata= DB::table("session_subservices")->where('id',$data['id'])->first();
        echo json_encode($servicedata);die;
    }
}

public function editCategoryService(Request $request){
    if($request->ajax()){
        $data = $request->all();
        //echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); die;
        SessionSubservice::where('id', $data['id'])->update(array('name' =>$data['name']));
        echo  $data['name']; die;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you append a new event every time the button is  clicked.

You need to remove the first event if you want to retain your approach.

Change this `$(document).on ('click','.editSubService',function(){`
to this:

`$(document).off('click').on('click','.editSubService',function(){`

Other aproach is to create a function in your js and set it to be called in the html.

Comment: not working click function not working. it working only once :(

Comment: I wrote the wrong class, i meant to say the function in the success of the ajax. Can you please try again ? I edited the answer.

Comment: still not working my modal not open again. it open only once :(

Comment: That's not a good idea as it will remove all click handlers from the `document`, not just the `.editSubService` one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `.editSubSerice` click handler:

```
$(document).on('click','.editSubService',function(){
   ...
}
```

You are adding this click handler in the `success` function of your ajax call which is part of another click handler, so every time that ajax call / click handler executes, you add an additional click handler and that causes the code to execute multiple times.

You should move that click handler to after (or before...) your other click handler so that it only gets called / binds once.

Comment: @kunal Can you post the modified code below the original and add what exactly is wrong with it?

Comment: @jeron i alreday shown my code at top. if you find some error please write code

Comment: @kunal Also note that I made a mistake, you need to move your click handler completely out of the other click handler.

Comment: but i need serviceid from first click handler thats why i used click function in ajax success

Comment: @kunal You can either set a global variable or get it from `$('#service_id')` as far as I can see.